# Capture substring at different positions from command's output in powershell

Tags: powershell, substring, text-parsing

I am running a command in windows terminal:

```
PS E:\> netsh wlan show profile name="wifi_profile" key=clear | findstr "Key Content"
    Key Content            : password1234
```

So here I am trying to get only `password123` (wifi password) **in output** for any profile

Is there any method in powershell by which I can do it?

Comment: You could split it at the colon and trim the leading and trailing spaces. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Olaf! 

`((((netsh wlan show profile name="wifi_profile" key=clear | findstr "Key Content") - split ":").trim()) -split "\r?\n")[1]`

Comment: `(netsh wlan show profile name="wifi_profile"  key=clear | Select-String "Key Content\s+:\s+(\S+)\s*").Matches.Groups[1].Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a simple cases like this, you can use the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator to trim the unwanted part of the line:

```
(
  netsh wlan show profile name="wifi_profile" key=clear | findstr "Key Content"
) -replace '^.+?: '
```

[Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) `^.+?:`  matches from the start (`^`) one or more (`+`) characters (`.`) non-greedily (`?`) until the (first) `:` followed by a space, and - in the absence of a replacement operand passed to `-replace` - replaces it with the empty string, i.e. effectively *removes* it, thereby only returning the value part.